# MS access calulcation with boolean

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to do a calculation in a query using MS Access. I am very new to this, I literally started using it a few days ago and some things have confused me.

I have a calculation that involves a booking system. So, in the system the user can book adults, children and the option of a car (Yes/No). I can get the correct calculation result for the adults and children by matching them with the Cost fields in my DESTINATION table. E.g Price for a car, Price for an adult, Price for a child. Just to note, this is so that the user can see their total in the next window by multiplying the quantity of adults/children with the prices and adding the car value if the Yes/No box is checked. But I do not know how to add the car value to the total as it is a Yes/No. I had other calculations that just messed everything up and I came to the code below:

> total: IIf([BOOKING]![Car]=True,[BOOKING]![Car]=[DESTINATION]![Price
>   for a Car],[BOOKING]![Car]=1)*[BOOKING]![Number of
>   Adults]*[DESTINATION]![Price for an Adult]+[BOOKING]![Number of
>   Children]*[DESTINATION]![Price for a Child]

However it doesn't add the car price to the total cost. Using the code above in the "Expression Builder" in "Query Design" managed to stop the calculations from returning random results. Am I going about this the wrong way? If so, how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets dissect the `Iif` function as you use it:

```
IIf(
    [BOOKING]![Car]=True,
    [BOOKING]![Car]=[DESTINATION]![Price for a Car],
    [BOOKING]![Car]=1
)
```

The first parameter is a boolean that can be either `True` or `False`. The second parameter is the value that is returned if the first parameter was `True`, the third parameter is returned otherwise.

Your first parameter tests if `[BOOKING]![Car]=True`. So far so good. Now, if  that comparison evaluates to true, the second parameter is returned. Since your second parameter is a comparison of `[BOOKING]![Car]` and `[DESTINATION]![Price for a Car]`, that will return `True` or `False` instead of what you probabaly really wanted it to return: `[DESTINATION]![Price for a Car]`.

Just remove `[BOOKING]![Car]=` from the second and third parameter and everything should be fine.

Comment: Removing the [BOOKING]![Car]= worked, thank you very much. However I still got incorrect results as that 1 at the false section of my expression should have been a 0. Not sure why I made it a 1.